# Redireccionar URL amigable de búsqueda en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, regex, .htaccess, redirección

Tengo un problema a la hora de redireccionar unas URLs amigables de búsqueda en Wordpress.

```
http://miweb.es/?s=&search_post_type=place&location=MiLocalizacion&category=MiCategoria
```

Lo que quiero es cambiar `MiLocalizacion` y `MiCategoria` por las variables que les paso mediante GET. La variable `place` de 'search_post_type' tiene que ser siempre la misma, por lo que no lo uso como variable.

La URL amigable que he creado previamente:

```
miweb.es/miBuscador/localizacion/categoria
```

He probado con la siguiente regla dentro de mi `.htaccess`:

```
# HTACCESS
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^miBuscador/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ http://miweb.es/?s=&search_post_type=place&location=$1&category=$2

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# END HTACCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

Si bien está un poco desordenado, en principio la regla está bien. Hay 2 cosas que cambiaría:

1. Lo único que podría no coincidir en tu regla es el `/` al final de la dirección. Podemos hacerlo opcional, `/?`.
2. Deberías estar redireccionando al archivo final, que asumo que es `index.php`.

```python
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Si va a index.php no hacer nada
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    #url amigable
    Rewriterule ^miBuscador/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?s=&search_post_type=place&location=$1&category=$2 [L]

    #otras carpetas o archivos
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

- Ejemplo funcionando:
  http://mariano.freevar.com/30337/miBuscador/MiLocalizacion/MiCategoria

Comment: En primer lugar, muchas gracias Mariano. He probado con lo que me dijiste y sigue sin funcionarme, he comprobado tu código y no se si será porque no usas WordPress y simplemente es codigo puro. ¿Es posible que el problema sea alguna función de WordPress? Gracias!

Comment: @Eva Es posible, pero no lo sé (no uso Wordpress). El `.htaccess` se evalúa **antes** que cualquier función de WordPress. ¿Qué es específicamente lo que no funciona? ¿El `index.php` está en el root de tu web? ¿Si vas a `http://miweb.es/index.php?s=&search_post_type=place&location=MiLocalizacion&category=MiCategoria` funciona?

Comment: El index está en el root, pero WordPress lee tanto index como plantillas. La URL de búsqueda [http://miweb.es/index.php?s=&search_post_type=place&location‌​=MiLocalizacion&cate‌​gory=MiCategoria] funciona

Comment: Si el archivo lo grabaste como `.htaccess` en el root, con exactamente este texto, y están bien los permisos del archivo, no sé qué más podría ser. Sólo quedaría esperar a que alguien más conteste.